# What causes compiling error with templated class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have simple codes for templated and non-templated versions of the same class. Each class has the same data structure (`Point`). The compiling problem happens for the templated class when defining the function with the structure `Point` externally. I compiled the codes with Visual Studio.

```
//non-templated class is defined without a compiling error.
class Geometry1 {
public:
    struct Point
    {
        double x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
    };
public:
    Point GetAPoint()//Function is defined internally
    {
        Point test;
        return test;
    }

    Point GetAnotherPoint();//Function will be defined externally
};

Geometry1::Point  Geometry1::GetAnotherPoint()//This externally defined function is fine with Point
{
    Point test;
    return test;
}


//Now a templated version of Geometry1 is defined. Compiling error happens!!!
template<typename type>
class Geometry2{
public:   
    struct Point
    {
        type x=1, y=2, z=3;   
    };
public:
    Point GetAPoint()//No compiling error
    {
        Point test;
        return test;
    }

    Point GetAnotherPoint();//Function will be defined externally WITH compiling error 
};

template<class type>
Geometry2<type>::Point  Geometry2<type>::GetAnotherPoint()//This externally defined function causes compiling error with Point: Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Point'
{
    Point test;
    return test;
}

int main()
{
    Geometry1 geo1;//There is compiling error for this class
    Geometry1::Point p1 = geo1.GetAnotherPoint();
    
    Geometry2<double> geo2;//Compiling error happens for this class
    Geometry2<double>::Point p2 = geo2.GetAPoint();
}
```

Complete error messages are:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Point'    TestClasstypedef    TestClasstypedef.cpp    51  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    TestClasstypedef    TestClasstypedef.cpp    52  
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   TestClasstypedef    TestClasstypedef.cpp    52  
Error   C2065   'geo1': undeclared identifier   TestClasstypedef    TestClasstypedef.cpp    60  
Error   C2065   'geo2': undeclared identifier   TestClasstypedef    TestClasstypedef.cpp    63
```

I found that if `Geometry2::GetAnotherPoint()` is defined internally like `Geometry2::GetAPoint()`, the problem will be completely solved.

Could anyone help me to figure out my mistake?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Change `Geometry2<type>::Point` to `typename Geometry2<type>::Point`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! It is completely solved. Best wishes!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that `Geometry2<type>::Point` is a **dependent qualified name**. Moreover, this dependent name is a **type** so you need to tell this to the compiler which you can do by adding the keyword `typename` before `Geometry2<type>::Point`. So the modified code looks like:

```
template<class type>
typename Geometry2<type>::Point Geometry2<type>::GetAnotherPoint()//note the keyword typename here
{
    Point test;
    return test;
}
```